# Concatting in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I got the following string in **thymeleaf** and I get the error:

> Could not parse as expression

```
th:onclick="'myFunction(\'$([[#new-' + ${e.var} +'_' +${l.var}]])+'\', true, false, true, false, true, myParameter);'"
```

Can't really see the concat mistake.

**Edit:** the $() is a jquery selector.

Thanks:)

Comment: How the final concated text should looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add plus sign on every phrase

here is something wrong, because you are ending phrase with apostrophe but you haven't plus sign after that

`myFunction(\'$([[#new-'`

apostrophe after `\` shouldn't be here, remove it

```
'\', true, false, true, false, true, myParameter);'"
```